# The name, 'auxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am having a problem with C#. I am using what I think is the correct code, but it gives me the error message: The name, " 'auxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL' does not exist in the current context"

Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\Users\BitCoin\Desktop\loic-code-42-tags-1.0.6\Resources\music.wmv";

    }
```

I might not be using the correct C# code for this, for I only know C++. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Typo: `ax...` vs. `aux...`? Also, where is it defined in relation to `button1_Click()`?

Comment: Where do you have axWindowsMediaPlayer1 defined??